# C# marshalling large struct to c DLL

Tags: c#, dll, struct, marshalling

I'm trying to access functions exported by some DLL (for accessing some specific hardware). The access to the functions using DLLImport and simple datatypes is working. But to some functions I need to pass some quite large structures. To overcome size limitations of automated marshalling I figured out to use IntPtr.

```
typedef struct
{
    double value[MemDepth];
    double offset[MemDepth];
    unsigned long start;
    BOOL active;
} RegisterData;

typedef struct 
{
    RegisterData a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
    BOOL active;
    BOOL test;
} Register;
```

And this is how I tried to put them in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RegisterData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = defines.MemDepth)]
    public double[] value;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = defines.MemDepth)]
    public double[] offset;

    UInt32 start;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool active;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Register
{
    RegisterData a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool active;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool test;
}
```

The function I'm trying to call looks the following in the DLL:

```
long ResetControl(Register* control);
```

Which I translated into:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 Reset(IntPtr control);
```

I'm then trying to call the function like this:

```
public Int32 lib_Reset(ref Register control)
{
    int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(control);

    //IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(size);
    IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

    System.Console.WriteLine("requested size of: " + size); // shows correct

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(control, ptr, false);

    System.Console.WriteLine("mem done");

    Int32 ret = Reset(ptr);

    System.Console.WriteLine("called reset");

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, control);
    System.Console.WriteLine("transfered back");

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
    //System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    System.Console.WriteLine("freeed mem");
    ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

    return ret;
}
```

This results in " A heap has been corrupted." when calling the DLLs Reset function. I already tried different ways but non worked.

**EDIT:**

I now got it working by cleaning and rebuilding the project using the IntPtr approach. It does not work directly using "ref". When using "ref" I always get:

```
 Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large.
```

I now do the following to convert from structure to pointer and back:

```
public Int32 lib_Reset(ref Register control)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(control);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.FreeHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(control, ptr, false);
    Int32 ret = Reset(ptr);
    control = (Register)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(control));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    return ret;
}
```

That way I can call Reset but it seems the functions does not do anything.

```
Register reg = new Register();

reg.active = true;
System.Console.WriteLine(reg.active);   // .active = true
lib_Reset(ref reg);         // should set .active = false
System.Console.WriteLine(reg.active);   // .active = true
```

The function Reset should initialize the Register structure. Thereby it sets active to false. But in the code shown above the value of active does not change. I tested the same with a integer value. It also did not change.

I hope anyone here can point me to the right direction in accessing the data.

Thank you,
Tobias

Comment: Is the exception thrown in your own code, and if so on which line, or in the external DLL?

Comment: I'm not sure. If I set breakpoints on the call of Reset and on the line after, I get after the first breakpoint: Critical error detected c0000374: First-chance exception at 0x77db380b in Test.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.

Comment: I think the DLL throws it. This _usually_ is because of freeing the same pointer / memory twice, but that's hard to see without the code for the DLL.

Comment: Thank you. I justed checked the code of the DLL and it only accesses the members of the struct to set some initial values.

Comment: After some more testing: the error does not always appear directly after calling Reset. Sometimes I get the "called reset" and also the "transferred back" message

Comment: You shouldn't need to mess with `IntPtr`. A simple `ref` should work fine. That is, `public static extern Int32 Reset(ref Register control);` It's possible that your "heap corruption" is due to structure packing. You might have to specify `Pack=1` or somesuch in your `StructLayout` attribute. Depends on how the C DLL was compiled.

Comment: Then I get: Additional information: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large. Thats why I moved to IntPtr

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. Cleaning and rebuilding the project did the trick. It is now working with the IntPtr approach. But the Reset function does not affect the values in the structure.

From the code of the DLL I know the elements should be initialized to some values. But the values of the elements do not change from before the call to after the call:

```
Register reg = new Register();

reg.active = true;
System.Console.WriteLine(reg.active);   // .active = true
lib_Reset(ref reg);         // should set .active = false
System.Console.WriteLine(reg.active);   // .active = true
```

The same fot the other elements. Is there something wrong with the conversion from structure to pointer and then back from pointer to structure?

If I take some value that is of integer type and I set it to 4 before the call it will be 4 after the call. So the values set before are preserved.

Comment: You should modify your question if you have further questions. Anyway if would avoid using a pointer and just use "ref" which is actually the same when doing interopt with C++.

Comment: o.k. I modified the question. sorry for that. The problem in using ref is that I cannot get it working. When using ref I get:  Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large.

Comment: Try to put the `OutAttribute` in front of the pointer. Maybe the CLI is wrapping the call in some way.

Comment: What do you mean by OutAttribute? Putting "out" instead of "ref"?

Comment: Nah, just write this: `Method([Out]MyStruct* param)`